# WordPress hook on creating a menu entry?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook

I need to run some code after a new item has been inserted into a WordPress [nav menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus).

Is there any hook on menu modification or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing but whatever you are asking the solution should be [save_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) `action hook` because you mentioned you need to add a menu item automatically in the menu bar whenever a new item is created and here new item could be a `post/page` or even a `nav_menu_item` and this hook executes on creating/updating of any of these items. So declare a hook in your `functions.php` file, something like this:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'item_has_been_saved' );
function item_has_been_saved($post_id)
{
    // $post_id is the newly created or updated item
    // use this $post_id to get the item and check it's type
    $item = get_post($post_id);
    //'post','page','link','nav_menu_item' or any custom post
    if($item->post_type == 'page') {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object('menu_name_goes_here');
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
        foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
            if($menu_item->post_name != $item->post_name) continue;
            else return false; // already exists
        }
        $newItem = array(
           'menu-item-title' =>  $menu_item->title,
           'menu-item-classes' => $menu_item->title,
           'menu-item-url' => $menu_item->url, 
           'menu-item-status' => 'publish'
        );
        wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu->term_id, 0, $newItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question and removed some irrelevant information so it is less confusing. On wordpress.stackexchange.com I've got exactly what I need: there's an action called 'wp_update_nav_menu'., but I think add_action( 'save_post', 'nav_menu_item' ); could also work, so I'm going to accept your answer.